# Cancellation of two limits with terms like $1/x$

Tags: limits

I'm hoping for some clarification on some applications of limits. I have a term $F(x)$ that looks like the following:

$$
F(x) = \frac{2(f(x)^2-1+x)}{x^2} + \frac{(f(x)f'(x)+1/2)^2}{f(x)^2-1+x}.
$$

I'm interested in the limit of this function:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} F(x)
$$

Because this is describing a physical system of interest to me, I need that this limit to not approach an infinity as $x\to 0$. Further, I know that as $x\to0$, $f(x)\to 1$. From this limit, the function $F(x)$ appears to blow up as $x\to0$. I see two possible solutions to this problem. Firstly, I can see that we could require that both terms independently must approach some fixed values. If I require this then taking the limit of both implies that the numerators must also approach $0$ so that we may take L'hopitals rule. From doing this manner, I can get that there is a solution which does not tend to infinity if: $f'(x)\to -1/2$ as $x\to 0$.

This method certainly seems to work and gives me a solution to the system. However, I was wondering if there is a more general solution where I do not assume that the two terms independently don't go to infinity, but instead assume that the terms cancel each other exactly. Is this a suitable method for finding another solution? Does it make sense mathematically? If so, what does the process of solving look like? Would I just group these terms into a common fraction and again look to use L'hopitals rule to find a similar relationship as above?

Apologies if this is a trivial limit problem. I'm quite removed from my fundamental math concepts at this point.

Edit: I will expand on the first set of solutions I found.

I want both terms to have an exact limit. Take the first term for example:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{2(f(x)^2-1+x)}{x^2},
$$

since the denominator goes to zero and the numerator goes to zero I use l'hopitals once to get:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{2f(x)f'(x) + 1}{x},
$$

the numerator goes to zero, so to continue evaluating this I need the numerator to also go to zero. By requiring $f'(x)\to -1/2$ in the limit the numerator goes to zero and we must then apply L'hopitals once more:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{2f(x)f''(x) + 2f'(x)^2}{1}
$$

So the first term in the limit of $x\to0$ gives:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{2(f(x)^2-1+x)}{x^2} = 2f''(x) + 1/2
$$

For the second term we have:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{(f(x)f'(x)+1/2)^2}{f(x)^2-1+x},
$$

we see based on the previous definition of $f'(0)=-1/2$ that the numerator and denominator both approach 0. L'hopitals on this gives:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{2(f(x)f'(x)+1/2)(f(x)f''(x)+f'(x)^2)}{2f(x)f'(x)+1},
$$

there is a cancelation and so this limit is also well defined:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{(f(x)f''(x)+f'(x)^2)}{1},
$$

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{(f(x)f'(x)+1/2)^2}{f(x)^2-1+x} = f''(x) + 1/4.
$$

So subject to the constraint that $f'(0)=-1/2$ the limit of $F(x)$ can be said to be:

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} F(x) = 3f''(x) + 3/4
$$

Comment: What limit, precisely?

Comment: Whoops, sorry I didn't write it precisely. One moment, I will edit the question.

Comment: @AndrewChin I've added the statement to the question for clarity

Comment: This question confuses me - As you noticed, if $f(x) \rightarrow 1$, then the left term goes to infinity, meaning $F(x)$ blows up. 
Then you say that you see "two possible solutions", one of them being that both of the terms has limits, but that's not true as we just noted, then I don't see how it's a solution, and what L'hopitals rule is doing here.
What did I miss?

Comment: @ReiHenigman I've added an example where I explain why I believe there is a single solution if we set that the function $f'(x)$ goes to $-1/2$ in the limit of $x\to0$ that does not blow up to infinity.

Comment: The second term also does not blow up under the same condition on $f'(x)$

Comment: OK, I haven't noticed that for $f'(x) = -\frac{1}{2}$ the left term has a limit :) Regarding your question - In general you can't "cancel out" two divergent sequences rigorously.
As you stated, the right direction is indeed "group these terms into a common fraction and again look to use L'hopitals rule to find a similar relationship as above".

Comment: @ReiHenigman thank you! I was worried that I had perhaps only been analyzing a subset of a more generalized solution. I'll probably re-organize my question and if anyone wants to expand on Rei's point on not being able to, in general, cancel two divergent sequences, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, I think my choice of words was pretty misleading even though I think you did understand me.
When I said 'can't "cancel out" two divergent sequences rigorously.', i meant you can't take their limits (+inf, -inf) and cancel them out. The way to see rigorously if they cancel each other is exactly adding the terms together to get a single term, and calculate their limit together, for example using L'hopitals. 
Sorry for being clumsy with my answers.